# Which API does Instagram use to perform 'see translation'

Tags: nlp, instagram

In Instagram people write comments in in  mixed language, for instance Hindi-English mixed, i.e Hindi transliterated text mixed with English words. Instagram provides a 'see translation' feature which converts the bilingual text into English.

Which API does Instagram use in order to translate the transliterated text into English?

```
Example comment:    'Mujhe office mein work hai'
Translated comment:  I have got work in office.
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, but it's owned by Facebook and facebook developed its own translation tool:
https://code.facebook.com/posts/1978007565818999/a-novel-approach-to-neural-machine-translation/

So it's no stretch to think instagram uses the same implementation.
Facebook used to use Bing translate before this.

Answer (score 1):

The example you gave has both transliteration and translation. Transliteration involves writing words of a language in an alphabet/script that is not native. Usually, this means that a non-English language is written using English alphabet. There could be some translation involved depending on which English words are used. I am not sure if transliteration APIs are publicly available but you can see an example of this from Google at [Google Language Input Tools](https://www.google.com/inputtools/try/).

If one was to develop such an API, a translation neural network could be used to "map" the English spelling to the original language word but that seems overkill since grammar is usually not an issue in such cases. A faster approach would be to use word2vec algorithm to align the embedded words.